# Show $Res_H^G(sgn_G)=sgn_H$ where $G=S_4$ and $H=S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

> Let $ G=S_3 $ and $ H=S_2 $. Show that $ Res^G_H(sgn_G)=sgn_H $

---

The symmetric group $G=S_3$  has three irreducible representations $ 1_G, sgn_G $ and $  V$ where $ 1_G $ denotes the trivial representation, $ sgn_G $ is the sign representation and $dimV=2  $.

$ S_2 $ is a subgroup of $ S_3 $, and $ 1_H $ and $  sgn_H$ are the irreducible representations of $ S_2 $ where $ 1_H $ is, of course, the trivial representation

---

I know that the restriction of a representation takes the representation of $G$ and maps it to a new representation of its subgroup $H$

The restriction of $sgn_G$ will go to either $1_H$ or $sgn_H$. How can we prove it goes to $sgn_H$?

Thank you

Comment: It follows directly from the definition. The sign of a permutation in $S_2$ is the same as its sign in $S_3$. The sign is a function of the permutation itself, so it makes no difference whether you consider it to be in $S_2$ or in $S_3$ or in $S_{25}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, what definition are you referring to in your first sentence? I would need to give some kind of formal proof

Comment: Just observe that $(12)$ acts by $-1$, so it isn't the trivial representation.

Comment: The definition of the restriction of the representation.